Firewall Advanced DoS D-link
Use a dlink router Model Name: DWR-M961
What is this and what does it do should I disable it I didn't understand whether it would affect my security If it remains activated
Enable Web Server HTTPS Access on WAN
Web Accessed IP Group 1:
Screenshot
Screenshot
I also activated all options Dos
But I don't know what this packets/second and block time(sec) Should I keep it at 0 or put a number?
